# String "ﬁgured" displayed as "?gured"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I am creating a program for a class where the program generates a random number that the user has to guess. I was able to get everything to work correctly except for the output display when the user guesses the correct number.

```
if (number == randomNum)
{
    cout << "Congratulations you have ﬁgured out my number."<<endl;
}
```

will display as

[image: a busy cat]

As you can see it will change `figured` to `?gured`. I am aware that I just change the message to display something different and not have this issue. Is there something that I am unaware of that about this language that does not like the word `figured`

Comment: it seems ﬁ is a unicode character that cant be displayed

Comment: you have a `ﬁ` not a `fi` in your string

Comment: How did you get unicode in your code?

Comment: Just delete the `ﬁ` and enter it again as `f` and `i`, and you will be fine. For whatever reason you got yourself a unicode character in there, probably from copy+paste.

Comment: @Mysticial: I'll bet the OP copied and pasted the string from a document (probably PDF or MS Word) containing the description of the assignment.

Comment: @KeithThompson you are correct and I am also a little embarrassed about not noticing that before

Comment: The character `ﬁ` is U+FB01, Unicode LATIN SMALL LIGATURE FI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your "ﬁ" seems to be a special character and not the letters f and i.

Use:

```
cout << "Congratulations you have figured out my number."<<endl;
```

Comment: Thank for for noticing that.